# Is it fine to have multiple foreign keys from one table to single primary key in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, database-design

Say I have two tables

**Products** table:

```
|ProductID|ProductName|ListPrice|
```

**PrebuiltSystems** table:

```
|BuldID|Processor|Motherboard|RAM|
```

The values for the Processor, Motherboard etc. are all existing `ProductID`'s. I am now creating
foreign key relationships from each of the part name columns to the one `ProductID` and have a bunch of navigation properties and relationships lines being created for each part. Is this ok?

Or is there some kind of relationship merger/rule that I can use to say all those columns are foreign keys to `productID` without creating one to one relationships ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is fine to have multiple foreign keys. However, in your example, I'd still do it differently; if you have one column for each component type you limit yourself very much. What do you do with a multi-CPU-system? What with multiple harddisks etc.?

You should rather normalize the PrebuiltSystems table so that you have a link table which creates a n-to-n relationship to the products (e.g. each product can be part of any number of prebuilt systems, and each prebuilt system can have any number of products in it).

Answer (score 3):

> Is this ok?

Yes, this is the right way to do it.

> Or is there somekind of relationship merger/rule that I can use to say
>   all those columns are foreign keys to productID

No, they are all different relationships.

> without creating one to one relationships ?

Note that these are **many-to-one**, not **one-to-one** relationships, many `PrebuiltSystems` will have the same `Processor`

Comment: +1 for the note about **one-to-one** / **many-to-one** relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. I had seen your answer (though I don't know why you put it is comment) because I wanted to additionally write about the arity point.

Comment: I put it as comment to leave the space for more detailed answers like yours.